# Finding the method name from an ExternalInterface.addCallback

Tags: actionscript-3, arguments, externalinterface

Let's say we have a number of `ExternalInterface.addCallback` functions, like so:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'foo', handler );
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'bar', handler );
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'foobar', handler );
```

In the function `handler` I'd like to find the method name called through the external interface, such as `foo, bar or foobar`; is there a way? Eg:

```
private function handler(...args):void
{
     arguments.callee.arguments[ 0 ];
}
```

But I doubt that'll work

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Just pass a parameter that identifies your function from the javascript, for example a string. So when you call the flash-function in your javascript code, pass a string, which you then parse in your handler function. For example:

actionscript:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'foo', handler );

private function handler(s:String):void
{
     if(s == "foo") {
       //foo specific code
     }
}
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('flashObj').foo("foo");
```

Comment: Hmm, not quite, you see the first argument of ExternalInterface.addCallback is the string for the method name you call from the JS, so ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'foo', handler ); would allow JS to call a function called foo() and this would be handled by handler() in the Flash.

Comment: Secondly, it's never a good idea to allow the passing of strings into a function, this'll make your app prone to hacking and possible XSS

Comment: you're right, it got mixed up somewhere.. And for the hacking thing, I was just pointing out that this is a possible way for this specific problem... But in any case, you're right though...

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but it will give you the info you need.
Just make the first parameter that you send the function name or in this case the object with funcname attribute so you can test if it exists.

JavaSCript

```
 function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
    thisMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").genericCallBack({ funcname:'foo' })
    thisMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").genericCallBack({ funcname:'poo' })
    thisMovie("ExternalInterfaceExample").genericCallBack({ funcname:'moo' })
```

AS3

```
public function foo( ):void{
  trace('in foo')
}

public function poo( ):void{
  trace('in poo')
}

public function moo( ):void{
  trace('in moo')
}
public function genericCallBack( o:Object ):void{
  trace( 'calling '+o.funcname)
  this[o.funcname]()
}


// add this somewhere in your init process
ExternalInterface.addCallback( 'genericCallBack', genericCallBack );
```

Comment: Again this is very prone to XSS attacking, essentially you're giving someone free reign over your app and since Flash can do cross site scripting, it's pretty dangerous. Good try though.

Comment: Any function call in JS is very prone to attack. SWFs can be decompiled/JS can be injected. If security is a major factor then you need to validate actions server side. You have to determine how many layers of security you need

Comment: Although, you never mentioned security in your question, so I really don't know what you are asking for now.

Comment: Essentially all I want to know is the method name of the callback that ExternalInterface has just handled. Essentially you're on the right path, as is ThomasM, but I'm not keen on letting arbitrary strings being passed to the application. It's not a case of hidden passwords in the app, it's a case to state the user can execute pretty much any public function in the app.